# Interacting with the Raydium API

Tags: spl, api, swap, raydium, sdk

I don't know much about programming. I want to interact with the Raydium API in order to swap tokens <30 secs after launch. How do I do it? A detailed guide would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are different programming languages you can do it in such as Typescript, Python and Rust. Solana library is available in all of these languages but Raydium library is not available in Python due to which you will have to manually write all the required raydium functions.

On the other hand, a similar question was answered earlier, which you can find [here](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8647/how-to-perform-a-swap-transaction-in-raydium-with-python/8656#8656). The answer may not be your detailed guide, but it may serve as your starting point.